# Java Error in Filtering Data in JTable using Combobox and Textfield

Tags: java

I have a problem in applying Filter in my JTable using Combobox and Textfield the problem is point at its resultset but inserting data from JTable is Fine but Filtering the data in JTable seems to trigger sql syntax please help

```
try {    
                String selection = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();          
                String query = "select * from tableemploy where " + selection +" = ? ";          
                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);              
                ps.setString(1, tsearch.getText());          
                rs = ps.executeQuery();              
                emptable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));          
                ps.close();
                rs.close();
                } 
            catch (Exception e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();   
                } 
        }
```

JComboBox

```
    Container box = getContentPane();
        box.setLayout(null);   
        box.add(combo = new JComboBox());
        combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Username"}));   
        combo.setBounds(410, 85, 100, 30);
        combo.setSelectedItem(null);
```

Comment: share the errors

Comment: emptable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));  it points to that line with error in sql syntax

Comment: they should be a set or errors , i want to see that

Comment: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)

Comment: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
 at base.UpdateEmploy.Search(UpdateEmploy.java:118)

Comment: try to print the complete and see if it is a valid sql syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad thats why it triggers sql syntax it because the combo box model must corresponds to sql rows